# How to play music tracks in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to play three musical tracks one after the other in a circle. It is necessary that its are not loaded again and were in the cache.
I use this code. Everything works fine on localhost, but only works after restart the app on the server. And wrong to re-download tracks every time.

```
public function musicOn():void{
    if (sndStart == 'true'){
        req = new URLRequest("media/" + track + ".mp3");
        snd.load(req);
        channel = snd.play(); 
        channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
        sndStart = 'false';
    } else {
        sndStart = 'true';
    }
}

public function musicOff():void{
    if (snd.length>0){
        channel.stop();
        snd = new Sound();
        channel = new SoundChannel();
        sndStart = 'true';
    }   
}

public function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event):void{ 
    if (track==3){
        track = 1;
    } else {
        track++;
    }
    sndStart = 'true';
    snd = new Sound();
    musicOn(); 
}
```

I run these functions:

```
if (optObj.music == 'true' && sndStart == 'true'){
    musicOn();
} else if (optObj.music == 'false'){
    musicOff();
}
```

`optObj.music` - it is the object with the parameters that is called when the app starts or when I call a function change the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand everything you wrote, but how about this one:

```
package test
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class SoundTest extends MovieClip 
{
    private var files : Array = [ "file1.mp3", "file2.mp3", "file3.mp3" ];
    private var sounds : Array = [];
    private var count : int = 0;
    private var channel : SoundChannel;


    public function musicOff () : void 
    {
        if (channel != null) 
        {
            channel.removeEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete );
            channel.stop( );
            channel = null;
        }
    }

    public function musicOn () : void 
    {
        if (sounds[count] == null) loadSound( );
        else playLoadedSound( );
    }

    private function loadSound () : void 
    {
        var sound : Sound = new Sound( );
        sound.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded );
        sound.load( new URLRequest( files[count] ) );
    }

    private function playLoadedSound () : void 
    {
        channel = sounds[count].play( );
        channel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete );
    }

    private function onSoundComplete (ev : Event) : void 
    {
        channel = null;
        count++;
        if (count >= files.length) count = 0;
        musicOn( );
    }

    private function onSoundLoaded (ev : Event) : void 
    {
        var snd : Sound = ev.target as Sound;
        sounds.push( snd );
        channel = snd.play( );
        channel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete );
    }

    public function SoundTest ()
    {
        musicOn( );
    }
}
}
```

(btw You can't play the Sound until it is loaded.  That's why your script works only after restart, when the mp3 is in the browser cache.)

Comment: Thanks weltraumpirat
But the same problem. If I call the function musicOn() after refresh,  music does not play the first time, but played only the second time.

Comment: Well then you must have some other problem, somewhere else in your program - I just tried the exact same script on my server, and it works fine.  Maybe it's the button calling the method?  Or did you put in the if (sndStart == 'true') from your script above?  Maybe you forgot to set sndStart = 'true' on program start?

Comment: Yes, the problem was elsewhere. I use a separate window settings, which passes the parameter to the main application. Somehow it does not always pass the proper options. Now I will deal. Thanks again.