# AS3 - How to import a class file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm a newbie to Adobe Flash CS 6 and ActionScript 3.0 (AS3). I have difficulties trying to understand how to include a class file into my project.

The problem is, I want to add a class file (.as) into my flash project (.fla). They are in the same folder with my project file (Courseware.fla and Courseware.as). Among the things that I have tried is:

On flash project:

```
import com.example;
```

On class file:

```
package com.example
{
    public class Test
    {
        public function display():void
        {
            trace("here");
        }
    }
}
```

But however, I received this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Master Frame', Frame 1, Line 1  1172: Definition com:example could not be found.
```

I'm clueless on how to fix this error. Can someone guide me on how to create and import class properly into a flash project? Thank you!

Comment: I've seen some of the tutorials, these are about class but I have completely no idea how to include it on my flash project. PLEASE HELP :'( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482675/how-to-play-music-tracks-in-as3

Comment: Do not use flash-cs5 to learn ActionScript. You well develop bad habits from it. Download FlashDevelop and give that a try. If anything it has better code hinting.

Comment: Thanks, I now program AS with flashdevelop. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. import com.example.* for importing all package or import com.example.Test for single class.
2. Class and file must have the same name (rename to Test.as or change class name to Courseware)
3. Test class file (Test.as) must be in com/example folder (create folders and copy class file ).

Comment: 1 word: "Lifesaver". Thank you for the answer, I'm once in the midst of hardship Googling trying to find how. Thank you very much!